# Transpose dynamic rows into columns

Tags: mysql, sql, transpose

I have two tables: one is `programs` and the other one is `bookprograms`.
The `programs` table is where you get the program name. The rows in this table can be added or edited.

I used the query below but it doesn't reflect if there is a new program:

```
SELECT  MAX(IF(programs = 'cla', title, NULL)) cla,
    MAX(IF(programs = 'csm', title, NULL)) csm
FROM    bookprograms
GROUP BY title
```

The structure of the first table.

```
╦════════════╦═════════════╗
║ ID         ║   Programs  ║
╬════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 1          ║     cla     ║
║ 2          ║     csm     ║
╩════════════╩═════════════╝
```

The second table is where I store the books and the program that corresponds to it.

```
╦════════════╦═════════════╗
║ Title      ║   Programs  ║
╬════════════╬═════════════╣
║ title1     ║     cla     ║
║ title2     ║     csm     ║
║ title3     ║     cla     ║
╩════════════╩═════════════╝
```

How would I come up with this result?

```
╦════════════╦═════════════╗
║ cla        ║   csm       ║
╬════════════╬═════════════╣
║ title1     ║   title     ║
║ title3     ║             ║
╩════════════╩═════════════╝
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query returns the data you need but not quite in the format you want it:

```
SELECT programs, GROUP_CONCAT(title) AS titles
FROM bookprograms
GROUP BY programs
```

It returns:

```
 programs | titles
----------+---------------
 cla      | title1,title3
 cls      | title2
```

In the client code you can morph this into the structure you need. The value of the header cell is returned in field `programs`. Split the value of field `title` by comma (`,`) and you have the data cells for the rest of the column. Repeat for each row from the result set to get all the columns of your desired table.

Comment: Thanks! This is a really big help.